# Showing a value in a custom module config page

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

i"ve been working on a custom module and i'm kind of stuck right now, basically when the module is installed it generates a token in the database and i would like to show the user that token in the config page.[image]

here is my system.xml part  that shows the field

```
<fields>
                <token_message>
                <label>Token</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <source_model>
            vendoflux/token
            </source_model> 
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
                </token_message>

            </fields>
```

i tried to send random data with the toOptionarray() function in my /model/token.php file but doesnt seem to work, any help would be appreciated

```
public function toOptionArray(){ 
return array(
        array('value'=>1, 'label'=>Mage::helper('vendoflux')->__('Hello')),              
    );
```

}

Comment: Did you get your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `source_model` for a `text` field, You need to use `select` or `multiselect` field.

Try below code,

```
<fields>
    <token_message>
        <label>Token</label>
        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
        <source_model>vendoflux/token</source_model> 
        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
    </token_message>
</fields>
```